# EclipseP5Exporter Error: Unable to complete export

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I am trying to export a processing project from eclipse using the proclipsing plugin, but it just keeps giving me this error. Here is the console output:

```
C:\Program Files\eclipse\lib\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path specified)
Exception: null :: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at dch.eclipse.p5Export.P5ExportWizard$1.run(P5ExportWizard.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\eclipse\lib\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at dch.eclipse.p5Export.P5ExportUtils.writeJarResourcesAsFiles(P5ExportUtils.java:269)
    at dch.eclipse.p5Export.P5ExportBuilder.<init>(P5ExportBuilder.java:104)
    at dch.eclipse.p5Export.P5ExportWizard.doFinish(P5ExportWizard.java:82)
    at dch.eclipse.p5Export.P5ExportWizard$1.run(P5ExportWizard.java:50)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: See that file that it can't find? Does that file exist?